# Simple Search on 13 Terabyte Oracle Database to return relevant rows (.net app? Java?)

Tags: oracle, query, full-text-search, c#, java

I am sure there are some easy ways to do this... I have a simple flat Oracle table which is 13 terabytes or so in size due to a large number of rows accumulating over the years.  I need to do a search on it (can be looking for matches on any of a number of fields), and would like to return the most relevant records in a list, like top 50 or top 100 which I can then click on for more detail (will then query specifically one field in that particular record).

What .net or Java - library or package would you recommend for this kind of search in Oracle?  Any chance there might be an example open source application or example like that out there that does this exact thing?  I am hoping to find something that allows me to prioritize matches in certain columns first, and finds matches quickly despite the large table size, and can easily be integrated into the second part of the requirement which is a regular query based on a "thread" to which that record belongs.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some useful hints in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202623/does-oracle-support-full-text-search).

If you are looking for alternatives to Oracle Text, have a look at [this](http://www.quora.com/Full-Text-Search/What-are-best-full-text-search-alternatives-to-Oracle-and-Lucene).